Is there a specific term for when someone turns a situation around to make it about them in a negative way?
The below is an example of the situation that describes the word or term I am looking for - btw, it may not exist! But I feel it should, so maybe it does.
My wife sprayed her spectacles with cleaner and the mist came my way a little, and it made me choke as I breathed it in - not much, but enough to elicit a physical, noticeable reaction. Her response was to glare at me and declare that, by my noises and actions, I obviously did not want her to be able to see properly. This seems an extrapolation too far.
Aside from the issues this example throws up in terms of harmonious marriage (), I wonder if there is a term for what happened in her brain to then provoke that small outburst. Like "straw man argument", "Pyrrhic victory" etc - I know those are not applicable terms for this situation, I'm just giving examples of terms that exist for other situations to further provide examples of what I am looking for.

Drama queen.....

Does she point the nozzle at you before she sprays?

I can commiserate since I'm very susceptible myself to aerosols.  But as it stands, your question is too broad and would elicit opinions on the dynamics of the situation.  It's like asking if there is there a term for people who slather themselves with strong perfume or cologne and then take offense if someone mentions it to them or stridently insist that they have  a right to use fragrances.

Playing the Victim

“Playing the victim” entails someone who is exaggerating or
fabricating an event, experience, or emotion to portray themselves as
a victim in the situation, when in reality they are not a victim. (ThriveWorks)


There can't be an expression capturing this situation better!  It would not be exaggerated to say that this person plays outrageously the victim, as what she pretends flies in the face of the simple evidence we are presented with.

With a little bit of narcissism perhaps.

@user66974 The discussion in this article speaks of narcissism as being a trait of character overlapping with the Main Character Syndrome, which one has been mentioned in the second answer (this answer is however but a comment).

@LPH I posted it as comment, as you can see!!! Btw I think this question is a POB one.

@user66974 You do mean a "peace out bitch" question?

Aside from self-victimization / playing the victim, I believe this situation has a tinge of Main Character Syndrome (or Main Character Energy) to it.
It covers the aspect of someone always taking a situation and making it about them, instead of allowing the interpretation that something simply happened in the world.

This is rather a comment on the problem of finding terms to describe the situation. The fact that the underlying explanation for the particular behaviour might be the Main Character Syndrome contributes nothing or little towards the goal of defining what is actually being done by this man's wife as a would-be consequence of that psychological trait of character.

I am aware, and yet the website says I need 50 reputation to leave a comment. Unless I am missing something, it seems that the mechanics of the forum encourage users like me to go ahead and try to give answers (or ask questions .. if they have any) to earn reputation.
